# GetInterface always return null

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I try to write a dll and called by a console program, partial coding as below,
But somehow, I have no idea why the getinterface always return null and then I can't invoke the function inside the dll.

MyDLL.dll

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    public interface IMyClass
    {
       void test();
    }

    public class MyClass : IMyClass
    {
       public void test()
       {
          // Do Something here
       }
    }
}
```

App:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        List<object> output = new List<object>();

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MyDLL.dll"));

        foreach (Type t in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterface("mynamespace.IMyClass") != null)
            {
                output.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(t));
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Log is written successfully. Press any key to exit");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I don't know why `t.GetInterface("mynamespace.IMyClass")` always return null?

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify your type name. By default .net will look for the type in the calling assembly.

```
if (t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterface("mynamespace.IMyClass, MYDLL") != null)
{
     output.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(t));
}
```

However, its just easier to use `Type.IsAssignableFrom()`

```
if (t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && typeof(IMyClass).IsAssignableFrom(t))
{
     output.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(t));
}
```